# convergence or divergence of exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we calculate whether the series $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^3}$ is convergent or divergent.

What i try:

For a Given series $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}, $  If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}\rightarrow 0.$ Then it is convergent.

In above series i take $\displaystyle a_{n}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^3}$. Then

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^3}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2n^4}+\frac{1}{3!n^6}+\cdots \bigg)\rightarrow 0$

So we can say the series $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}$ Converge.

Is my reasoning is true for that problem

If false . Then please explain me how do i solve it, Thanks

Comment: It's overkill.  Simpler version $e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\le e$.  Therefore $a_n\le \frac{e}{n^n}\to 0$.  Also $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^3}?$$

Comment: As Surb says in his answer, it is *very  much not* sufficient to show that $a_n \to 0$ if you want to show that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: No. That $a_n \to 0$ is *necesary* for convergence, but not *sufficient* (consider the divergent \sum 1/n$).

Answer (score 2):

No, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }a_n=0$ is not enough for the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ (example : $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$).

**Hint**

In your case, $$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^3}=\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

No, the reasoning is wrong because you are adding an infinity of $a_n$ terms (it is a sum of sums) and you need a deeper justification.

Anyway, it suffices to notice that

$$e^{1/n^2}\le e.$$

Comment: Thanks Yves DAoust. Means $\sum \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^3}\leq e\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$. Now from $p$ series test. We can say that it is coverge.

Comment: @jacky: that's it.

Comment: Thanku very much to all professors.